# Access crashes then query design button clicked on written sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

The query works pretty fine, I can view result as a table and sql code on his own without any problem. However then I try to press `query design` button, it crashed without saying why. [image]

My code is pretty simple, after I added one more `left join` out of `A` subquery such error started to appear. This way last `left join` definitely cause the problem.  Tried to join without using subquery but I get problem saying about ambiguous outer join. I'm newbie with access but I heard about several bugs in that program, any suggestion how to fix?

This problem query:

```
    select    A.*,targetresp.* 
    from      (
    SELECT  * 
    FROM   target INNER JOIN ((source INNER JOIN InstanceList 
                    ON   source.INFO_SYSTEM_TYPE_CD = InstanceList.INFO_SYSTEM_TYPE_CD) 
INNER JOIN (N_table_transform INNER JOIN S2T 
                    ON    N_table_transform.N_table = S2T.N_table) 
                    ON    source.ID = S2T.source_id) 
                    ON    target.id = S2T.target_id ) as A

    left join targetresp 
                    on          a.target_TableName = targetresp.tablename;
```

Comment: when you ask a question try to simplify the issue. For example all those fields doesnt add to the issue, a `select *` is just enough. Now the best think you can do is add one inner join at a time and try to see where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT InstanceList.*
FROM 
    N_table_transform 
    INNER JOIN (((S2T INNER JOIN target 
                  ON S2T.target_id = target.Id) 
    LEFT JOIN targetresp ON target.target_TableName = targetresp.target_TableName) 
    INNER JOIN (InstanceList 
    INNER JOIN source ON InstanceList.INFO_SYSTEM_TYPE_CD = source.INFO_SYSTEM_TYPE_CD) 
    ON S2T.source_id = source.Id) 
    ON N_table_transform.N_table = S2T.N_table;
```

I just use the access 2013 designer and build the query.

[image]

On the bottom switch between SQL and DESIGNER

[image]

Comment: Yea, you  will be right If I use normal DBMS, but this boring Access, which requires  parentheses in the `FROM` clause for queries which include more than one join, look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929332/multiple-inner-join-sql-access

Comment: As your question is regarding the last `left join` try do that first and go backwards instead. Also your link show you can use designer to add the join and this will add the parenthesis for you

Comment: Can you check my update answer and let me know? I just create your schema db the best I could (hope is ok) and then use designer to build the query. Hope access 2013 is similar to 2010