# Convert subquery to a standard query using INNER JOIN syntax

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, subquery

I am using an Access Database and need help converting the following nested query into an inner join query.

The DIRNUM is the primary key in the DIRECTOR table and it is also in the MOVIE table. The MVNUM is the primary key in the MOVIE table and MOVSTAR table.

```
SELECT dirname 
FROM director
WHERE dirnum IN (SELECT dirnum 
                 FROM movie 
                 WHERE mvnum IN  (SELECT mvnum 
                                  FROM movstar 
                                  WHERE starnum=2)
                );
```

Comment: pls format your post in a better way

Answer (score 2):

You want to select distinct (since you aren't using "WHERE IN" syntax, you will get duplicates)

```
SELECT DISTINCT dirname 
FROM 
    (director d
INNER JOIN 
    movie m ON m.dirnum = d.dirnum)
INNER JOIN
    movstar ms ON ms.mvnum = m.mvnum
WHERE
    ms.starnum=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    dirname 
FROM 
    (director d
INNER JOIN 
    movie m ON m.dirnum = d.dirnum)
INNER JOIN
    movstar ms ON ms.mvnum = m.mvnum
WHERE
    ms.starnum=2
```

EDIT: Altered to add parenthesis as pointed out by HansUp

Comment: [Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause for queries which include more than one join.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20929533/77335)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that. ;)