# Multiple INNER JOINS in Access db from delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, syntax

I wrote simpliest program that connect to acceessdb and from Memo column I can execute SQL query.

Example query:

```
SELECT 
    company_name, date_of_order_start, date_of_order_finish
FROM 
    customers
INNER JOIN 
    orders ON customers.id_customer = orders.id_customer
WHERE 
    company_name='Ампер';
```

It works fine, but this query

```
SELECT 
    company_name, date_of_order_start, date_of_order_finish, amount
FROM 
    customers
INNER JOIN 
    orders ON customers.id_customer = orders.id_customer
INNER JOIN 
    invoice ON invoice.id_order = orders.id_order
WHERE 
    company_name='Ампер';
```

returns a syntax error

> missing operator in expression 'customers.id_customer=orders.id_customer
>   INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice.id_order=orders.id_orde' .

Yes, the final `r` in `.id_order` isn't showing.

Please help, where I made mistake.

Below the code of the program

```
    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.DBCtrls,
  Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Data.Win.ADODB;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//проверим - есть ли текст в Memo. Если нет, выходим:
  if Memo1.Text = '' then begin
    ShowMessage('Вначале введите запрос!');
    Memo1.SetFocus;
    Exit;
  end;
  //текст есть. Очистим предыдущий запрос в наборе данных:
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  //добавим новый запрос из Memo:
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(Memo1.Text);
  //открываем набор данных, т.е. выполняем запрос:
ADOQuery1.Open;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(Memo1.Text);
  ADOQuery1.SQL := Memo1.Lines;
end;


end.
```

Comment: Seems that the text of the query is truncated. I suggest to debug Delphi application and check what values is stored in text variable

Comment: Please show the code where you're retrieving the SQL text from the memo control and putting it into your ADOQuery.SQL. I'd also suggest you alias all of your tables and columns, as in `SELECT c.company_name, o.date_of_order_start, o.date_of_order_finish FROM customers c INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer`, to avoid any accidental conflicts with column names (and to type less).

Comment: I added code to the main text. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Your assignments to ADOQuery1.SQL in Memo1Change seem to be in conflict, but I assume that you don't need either of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple INNER JOIN SQL ACCESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929332/multiple-inner-join-sql-access)

Answer (score 2):

Great thanks everyone who try to help me!

In access db JOIN must be in (), so this query works fine:

```
 SELECT 
company_name, date_of_order_start, date_of_order_finish, amount
    FROM 
(customers
    INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id_customer=orders.id_customer)
    INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice.id_order=orders.id_order
    WHERE company_name='Ампер';
```

Comment: Correct name of the question is very important. Please rename your question with more accurate description of the problem.
Here's the answer of your question with a bad name : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929332/multiple-inner-join-sql-access

Comment: You are right, but when I wrote question I don`t understand where is the problem.

Comment: Yes of course, but now let's do it useful for other people :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding error handling around your query:

```
Try
  ....
  // setup and execute your query

    except on e: exception do
      begin
        LogMyErrorSomehow(format('ERROR: [%s-%s] SQL:[%s]',
           [e.ClassType.ClassName, e.Message, ADOQuery1.SQL.text]));
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem which IP is facing - it only provides the ability to report the error more appropriately.

Comment: I think the actual problem is that the OP doesn't have basic debugging/troubleshooting skills, so yes this does help solve his problem.

Comment: Yer, you are right) I haven`t) actually I am beginner web developer and this task for my university work.

Answer (score 1):

one more information: here you write the Memo1.Text two times to ADOQuery1.SQL

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(Memo1.Text);       // <-- first time
  ADOQuery1.SQL := Memo1.Lines;        // <-- 2nd time
end;
```

you write the statement to the ADOQuery1 here:

```
 //текст есть. Очистим предыдущий запрос в наборе данных:
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  //добавим новый запрос из Memo:
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(Memo1.Text);
```