# Finding parents by their children's properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a database containing information about members of a choir (which is divided into sections) and their parents. I need to build an e-mail list containing all children in a specific section of the choir as well as their parents.

There is a large table `COMPersonen` which contains all the personal information I need (especially their ID number `Nummer` and primary e-mail address `Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse`).

Another table `COMPBereiche` contains all the details about which section(s) (`Bereich (Nr)`) of the choir a certain person belonged to at a certain time. It is linked to the primary table via `Nummer`/`Person (Nr)`. The `[Bis]` (= "until") field can be used to determine whether a person is currently a section member by checking if that field is either empty or set to a future date.

Lastly (at least for this purpose) there is a table `COMElternKind` that contains the ID number of all the parents (`Elternteil (Nr)`) and the ID numbers of their children (`Kind (Nr)`). Of course, each parent can have more than one child and vice versa.

So far, this is pretty straightforward. In Access, the relations look like this:

[image: Database relations]

The easy part was building a query that returns all the addresses for the children in a specific section of the choir (for example the section with the ID `Bereich (Nr) = 4`):

```
SELECT COMPersonen.Nummer, COMPersonen.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse],
       COMPBereiche.[Bereich (Nr)], COMPBereiche.Bis
FROM COMPersonen 
INNER JOIN COMPBereiche ON COMPersonen.[Nummer] = COMPBereiche.[Person (Nr)]
WHERE (((COMPersonen.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse]) Is Not Null) 
AND ((COMPBereiche.[Bereich (Nr)])=4) 
AND ((COMPBereiche.[Bis]) Is Null Or (COMPBereiche.[Bis])>=Date()));
```

But now I also need the addresses of the **parents** whose children are in section 4 of the choir at the moment. How would I go about that? Finally, the two `SELECT` statements would need to be combined, but my guess is that that's a simple `UNION`, right?

Comment: Could you use a subselect using your existing query? `select persons.email as parent_email where child_id in (select id from my_existing_query)`

Comment: Sounds plausible, I just need to find a way to get to `child_id`...let my try...

Comment: do you want only parents whose children are in section 4? or you need both in separete rows in your query? or in same rows like parent, email, children, email?

Comment: Yes, only those parents. At least that would be my first step - one query for the children, one for the parents. Ideally, I'd like to have their union - a single column of all e-mail addresses both of the children in section 4 and the parents of the children in section 4.

Comment: ok, give me 3 minute

Comment: Is this microsoft access?

Comment: It's a custom app that makes use of an MS Access database, yes.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `COMPersonenRel1`; shouldn't table `COMPBereiche` reference directly `COMPersonen`?

Comment: You're right, it works without that - will edit my question shortly.

Comment: It is my impression that your first query is too complex, and as I started working on it I really cannot see the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think that this is too simplistic?

First query (children):

```
SELECT p.*, b.[Bereich (Nr)]
FROM COMPBereiche b INNER JOIN COMPersonen p ON b.[Person (Nr)] = p.Nummer 
WHERE b.[Bereich (Nr)] = 1001 
AND (b.Bis IS NULL OR b.Bis >= '2016-01-01')
and p.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse] IS NOT NULL
```

Second query (parents):

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW e.*
FROM ((COMPBereiche b INNER JOIN COMPersonen p ON b.[Person (Nr)] = p.Nummer) 
INNER JOIN COMElternKind k ON p.Nummer = k.[Kind (Nr)])
INNER JOIN COMPersonen e ON e.Nummer = k.[Elternteil (Nr)]
WHERE b.[Bereich (Nr)] = 1001 
AND (b.Bis IS NULL OR b.Bis >= '2016-01-01')
AND e.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Test the field names, there might be a misspel somewhere.

Comment: Can it be that I spelled ElternTeil with capital T? You have it written as "Elternteil"

Comment: You have to break it to pieces then, start by a small `select * from COMPBereiche`; if it works (it will!) add the first two parts of the `where` clause (pay attention to the alias `b`, it must be introduced in the `from` clause), then start adding joins one by one. Let me know up to which point it works and when exactly it starts breaking down (I don't have MS Access installed, so this is the best I can do).

Comment: The error is most likely because microsoft access requires parentheses in the `from` clause when you have more than 1 join. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20929533/2333499

Comment: Thank you @SqlZim, let's see if this is indeed the case.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll edit the answer to show the query that worked. The only drawback remaining is that some e-mail addresses are duplicated when a parent has more than one child.

Comment: This can be solved easily with a `distinct`. Should you consider removing the `Bereich (Nr)` from the result set?

Comment: @TimPietzcker "duplicated when a parent has more than one child" **or** when a child belongs to more than one Bereich - or is this not possible? If it is, the `distinct` should be applied to the first query as well.

Comment: There can be only one Bereich at one moment in time. Adding `DISTINCTROW` to the first query solved the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Kein Problem, mfG aus Athen!

Answer (score 1):

every parent+children whose have children in your logic, rowcount will be equal children count

```
select prnt.[Nummer] as parentnum, prnt.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse] as parentemail,
           prnt.[Bereich (Nr)] parentBereinch, prnt.[Bis] parentBis, chld.*
           from COMPersonen prnt 
  INNER JOIN COMelternKind cmk, ON prnt.[Person (Nr)] = cmk.[Elternteil (Nr)] 
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT COMPersonen.Nummer as chldnum, COMPersonen.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse],
           COMPBereiche.[Bereich (Nr)], COMPBereiche.Bis
    FROM COMPersonen 
    INNER JOIN (COMPersonenRel1 
        INNER JOIN COMPBereiche 
        ON COMPersonenRel1.[Person (Nr)] = COMPBereiche.[Person (Nr)]) 
    ON COMPersonen.[Nummer] = COMPersonenRel1.[Person (Nr)]
    WHERE (((COMPersonen.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse]) Is Not Null) 
    AND ((COMPBereiche.[Bereich (Nr)])=4) 
    AND ((COMPBereiche.[Bis]) Is Null Or (COMPBereiche.[Bis])>=Date()))) chld
ON cmk.[Kind (Nr)]) = chld.[chldnum]
```

every parent whose have children in your logic, rowcount will be only parents count

```
select * from COMPersonen prnt 
  INNER JOIN COMelternKind cmk, ON prnt.[Person (Nr)] = cmk.[Elternteil (Nr)]

  where exists (SELECT COMPersonen.Nummer as chldnum, COMPersonen.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse],
           COMPBereiche.[Bereich (Nr)], COMPBereiche.Bis
    FROM COMPersonen 
    INNER JOIN (COMPersonenRel1 
        INNER JOIN COMPBereiche 
        ON COMPersonenRel1.[Person (Nr)] = COMPBereiche.[Person (Nr)]) 
    ON COMPersonen.[Nummer] = COMPersonenRel1.[Person (Nr)]
    WHERE ((COMPersonen.Nummer = cmk.[Kind (Nr)])  
    AND ((COMPersonen.[Serienbrief E-Mail Adresse]) Is Not Null) 
    AND ((COMPBereiche.[Bereich (Nr)])=4) 
    AND ((COMPBereiche.[Bis]) Is Null Or (COMPBereiche.[Bis])>=Date())))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the problem better. I didn't get your solution to work, perhaps because of the quirks of MSSQL's syntax, but I appreciate your input very much.