# MS Access VBA: Syntax error with inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am attempting to add a simple inner join to a MS Access query. I am trying to connect a table with a single field simply to restrict results to a subset of cusnums. I am getting a Syntax error (See below) that I simply do not understand.

I included the old code and the new code below. The only change is the addition of the inner join. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Error Message:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

```
'(qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum = tbl_Store_With_Sat_Ord.shpcusnum)
LEFT JOIN 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out 
ON      
        (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.co_num = qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.co_num) 
    AND 
        (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum = qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.shpcusnum'
```

Old Code:

```
SELECT 
        IIf([totordqty]>0, "Order In","No Order") AS OO_Staus, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.co_num, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.prislscod, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.co_nam, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusphn, 
        Switch([totordqty]>0,"",[cusphn]<>"",[cusphn],True,"No Phone # on File") AS Cust_Phone, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.rtedow, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.rtecod, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.stpnum, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.plnshpdat, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.totordqty, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.ordnetwgt, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.ordcub, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.shptotamt, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.prcflg, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusemaadd, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.TD_Email
FROM 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out 
LEFT JOIN 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out 
ON 
        (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.co_num = qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.co_num) 
    AND 
        (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum = qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.shpcusnum)
WHERE 
        (((IIf([totordqty]>0,"Order In","No Order"))="No Order"))
ORDER BY 
        IIf([totordqty]>0,"Order In","No Order"), 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.rtecod, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.stpnum;
```

New Code:

```
SELECT 
        IIf([totordqty]>0,"Order In","No Order") AS OO_Staus, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.co_num, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.prislscod, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.co_nam, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusphn, 
        Switch([totordqty]>0,"",[cusphn]<>"",[cusphn],True,"No Phone # on File") AS Cust_Phone, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.rtedow, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.rtecod, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.stpnum, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.plnshpdat, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.totordqty, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.ordnetwgt, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.ordcub, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.shptotamt, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.prcflg, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusemaadd, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.TD_Email
FROM 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out 
INNER JOIN
        tbl_Store_With_Sat_Ord
ON
        (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum = tbl_Store_With_Sat_Ord.shpcusnum)
LEFT JOIN 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out 
ON      
        (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.co_num = qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.co_num) 
    AND 
        (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum = qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.shpcusnum)
WHERE 
        (((IIf([totordqty]>0,"Order In","No Order"))="No Order"))
ORDER BY 
        IIf([totordqty]>0,"Order In","No Order"), 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.rtecod, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.stpnum;
```

Comment: Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause for queries which include more than one join. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929332/multiple-inner-join-sql-access/20929533#20929533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `FROM` section onwards of your SQL code to:

```
FROM 
(
            qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out 
    LEFT JOIN 
            qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out 
    ON      
            (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.co_num = qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.co_num) 
        AND 
            (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum = qry_Co_1_PRET_Open_Order_2_Days_Out.shpcusnum)
)
INNER JOIN
        tbl_Store_With_Sat_Ord
ON
        (qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.cusnum = tbl_Store_With_Sat_Ord.shpcusnum)
WHERE 
        [totordqty] <= 0
ORDER BY 
        [totordqty] <= 0, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.rtecod, 
        qry_Co_1_PRET_Routed_2_Days_Out.stpnum;
```

Note the changes to the `WHERE` & `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: This answered my question, thank you. A note however: changing the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses caused it to return no records. I changed it back to the original and I am now getting the correct results.

Comment: @joshusmu That's odd given that the logic is obviously the same. I can only assume there may be null values, hence the `WHERE` clause may need to be `[totordqty] <= 0 OR [totordqty] IS NULL`. Just a guess however without seeing the data.