# Aliases for 2 joins on one table in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that shows relationships between items and another table with the items themselves:

```
articles_to_articles
-------------------------
|articleID_1|articleID_2|
-------------------------
|12345      |67890      |
|23442      |343243     |
-------------------------

articles
-----------------------------------------------------
|article_id | article_name|lots | of | other | stuff|
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I am attempting to generate a file with that consists of the relationships from `articles_to_articles` but with the names in addition to the ids.
What I have so far is:

```
    SELECT
    a2a.articleID_1,
    key_articles.article_name,
    a2a.articleID_2,
    val_articles.article_name 
FROM
    articles_to_articles a2a
INNER JOIN
    articles key_articles 
        ON key_articles.articleID = articles_to_articles.articleID_1 
INNER JOIN
    articles val_articles 
        ON val_articles.articleID = articles_to_articles.articleID_2;
```

Access gives me a "missing operator" error but I can't seem to find the missing operator. What basic thing am I missing?

Comment: [Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause for queries which include more than one join.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929533/77335)

Comment: Thank you! There's always something, and you taught me yet another useful syntactic detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When joining more than two tables in MS Access, you must enclose each join within separate groups of parentheses, for example:

```
SELECT
    a2a.articleID_1,
    key_articles.article_name,
    a2a.articleID_2,
    val_articles.article_name 
FROM
    (
        articles_to_articles a2a
        INNER JOIN
        articles key_articles 
        ON 
        key_articles.articleID = a2a.articleID_1 
    )
    INNER JOIN
    articles val_articles 
    ON 
    val_articles.articleID = a2a.articleID_2
```