# How to add a field from another table to a left join query MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that involves both left join and not exists statements. Thus this query is not supported in design view. I would like to add a field "comments" from another table "Table2". Is this possible with the query I have created? The code is as follows:

```
SELECT t.NUM, t.ID, tprev.Date_ AS previous_date, tprev.Measurement AS previous_measurement
FROM Table1 AS t LEFT JOIN
     Table1 AS tprev
     ON (tprev.id = t.id) AND (tprev.Date_ < t.Date_)
WHERE not exists 
        (select 1
        from Table1 AS t1
        where 
            t1.ID = t.ID
            and t1.Date_ < t.Date_
            and t1.Date_ > tprev.Date_);
```

Comment: Sure, you would have to join `table2` thatfore.

Comment: Where do I place the join?

Comment: This is my join attempt: SELECT t.NUM, t.ID, tprev.Date_ AS previous_date, tprev.Measurement AS previous_measurement, t3.Comments
FROM Table1 AS t LEFT JOIN Table1 AS tprev ON (tprev.id = t.id) AND (tprev.Date_ < t.Date_)
JOIN Table2 AS t3 ON t.NUM = t3.Comments
WHERE not exists 
        (select 1
        from Table1 AS t1
        where 
            t1.ID = t.ID
            and t1.Date_ < t.Date_
            and t1.Date_ > tprev.Date_)
Error is "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(tprev.id = t.id) AND (tprev.Date_ < t.Date_) Join Table2 AS t3 ON t.NUM = t3.Comment"

Comment: You need parentheses if you use multiple joins and you can't nest them in all ways, depending on their join-type. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929533/7658533 and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/left-join-right-join-operations-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: From the second link: "A LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN can be nested inside an INNER JOIN, but an INNER JOIN cannot be nested inside a LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN. See the discussion of nesting in the INNER JOIN topic to see how to nest joins within other joins."

Comment: I used both the links and the information you provided. It still isn't quite working and I'm getting a syntax error. Here is what I have: SELECT t.NUM, t.ID, tprev.Date_ AS previous_date, tprev.Measurement AS previous_measurement
FROM ((Table2 AS t2 INNER JOIN Table1 AS t ON (t2.Comments = t.ID)) LEFT JOIN Table1 AS tprev ON tprev.Date_ < t.Date_) AND (tprev.id = t.id))
WHERE not exists 
        (select 1
        from Table1 AS t1
        where 
            t1.ID = t.ID
            and t1.Date_ < t.Date_
            and t1.Date_ > tprev.Date_);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example of your last comment, this query works without any complains regarding syntax:

```
SELECT t.NUM, t.ID, tprev.Date_ AS previous_date, tprev.Measurement AS previous_measurement
FROM (
     (
     Table2 AS t2
     INNER JOIN Table1 AS t
       ON (t2.Comments = t.ID)
     )
     LEFT JOIN Table1 AS tprev
       ON tprev.Date_ < t.Date_ AND tprev.id = t.id
     )
     WHERE not exists (select 1 from Table1 AS t1 where t1.ID = t.ID and t1.Date_ < t.Date_ and t1.Date_ > tprev.Date_);
```

The reason for the syntax error was that this parenthesis `t.Date_)` was too much.

If it is logically fine, you should know.

What smells a bit are those:

- You compare `Comments` with `ID`. Maybe it should be `CommentID`?
- The fieldname `Date_`. Maybe you can find a better name without having to use an underscore?

## Update

Following the comments of this answer and the new requirements, this should be what you need:

```
SELECT
  t.NUM, t.ID, tprev.Date_ AS previous_date, tprev.Measurement AS previous_measurement, t2.Comments
FROM
  (
  Table1 AS t
  LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2
    ON t.ID = t2.ID
  )
  LEFT JOIN Table1 AS tprev
    ON (tprev.id = t.id) AND (tprev.Date_ < t.Date_)
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.ID = t.ID AND t1.Date_ < t.Date_ AND t1.Date_ > tprev.Date_)
```

It finally is the query of your question enhanced by another left join to add the column `Comments` from `table2` where a corresponding comment exists.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. I realize I may have been unclear on how I need the query to perform. Table2 consists of two fields, "ID" and comments. Table1 has repeating IDs but table two only has one line entry for every ID. I want the comments from Table2 to match with the ID in from Table1. I will put my code in the following comment but it is not printing any values in the comments field. Hopefully this makes sense...

Comment: SELECT t.NUM, t.ID, tprev.Date_ AS previous_date, tprev.Measurement AS previous_measurement, t2.Comments AS Comments
FROM (
     (
     Table1 AS t
     LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2
       ON (t2.ID = t.ID) AND (t2.Comments = t.ID)
     )
     LEFT JOIN Table1 AS tprev
       ON tprev.Date_ < t.Date_ AND tprev.id = t.id
     )
     WHERE not exists (select 1 from Table1 AS t1 where t1.ID = t.ID and t1.Date_ < t.Date_ and t1.Date_ > tprev.Date_);

Comment: Do you want the join to `table2` to restrict the overall result, or do you just want to add the column `Comments` from `table2` where it exists (by `ID`) to the result?

Comment: No, I do not want table2 to restrict the overall result.