# Ms Access queries cannot run

Tags: ms-access

im writng sql queries for my coursework but upon completing the code it says characters found after an sql statement but im not sure where its going wrong. this is my first time using SQL and creating a database with ms access so thank you for any help and suggestions.

[image: SQL code]

edit: here are the queries
Implement a database based on the design produced as per above requirements. The
prototype database is to be built using any competent technology/tools you are
familiar with (MS Access is fine for the prototype)
Once you built the database, it should provide enough functionality to be able to run
the following SQL queries:

- Add a patient to the system
- Update patient details to inform their preferences (such as their location and
  nearest available GP clinic)
- Delete patient details
- Add an appointment in the system
- View the status of a particular appointment
- View the history of all the appointments for a particular patient including
  patient ID, surgery name and appointment time

Comment: If you don't share the query, we can't help.  Try editing your question, and include EVERYTHING in the SQL statement.  Usually, SQL statements end in `;`

Comment: oh sorry i added the queries!

Comment: i tried this im not sure if it worked as when i run it it still says 'chareters found at the end of sql statment' however the line 'UPDATE Patient;' is highlighted

Answer (score 1):

Your query contains multiple SQL statements. However Access does not allow you to batch them together as a single query.  Each `INSERT, UPDATE, UPDATE,` and `SELECT` statement must be a separate query.

Batching them together in one Access query is the cause of your error: *"Characters found after end of SQL statement."*  Here is a simpler example which triggers the same error message:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (user_name)
VALUES ('billy');
UPDATE MyTable SET user_name = 'william'
WHERE user_name = 'billy';
```

Then if I divide that SQL into 2 queries --- one for the `INSERT` and another for the `UPDATE` --- both queries run without error.

After you fix the current error, it seems you will encounter a different error with the last `SELECT` because it joins more than 2 tables and [Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause for queries which include more than one join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929533/77335).  Use the query designer to set up your joins; it will add the needed parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell in your image, the problem is after your last line.

```
    ...
     WHERE Patient.PatientID =1;


    

x
```

I added the "x' at the bottom, but I see your cursor is located several lines below the last statement.

Try removing all whitespace after the last semicolon.

PS, you should not send an image, but cut and paste the code into Stack-Overflow.  Use the code symbol in the inline editor to signify code.  It might even help you find out the problem as you are copying it over.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but this did not seem to work, however when i run it this code gets highlighted: UPDATE Patient;  specifically the 'UPDATED' part is there a problem in that line?

Comment: do you have a table named `AdditionalInformation` with a column named `HomeLocation`?  If so, is `HomeLocation` a text format?