# Append table by looking up values from imported data in other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have raw data imported with columns containing a Training ID (Item ID), a Trainer (Column 1), an Evaluator (Column 2), and an identifier for the combination of those 3 values (Column 3).

When importing this data, a query will append a table called People with both Trainers and Evaluators. Another will append a table called Trainings. I have a third query for appending a table called Surveys which will store all 4 of the values listed here, but I want it to refer to the People and Trainings tables, rather than duplicate the values directly from the import.

I have the following SQL query written, but when I try to save it, Access says, "Syntax error (missing operator)". Where is the syntax error, and is there a better way to write this query?

```
INSERT INTO Surveys (Trainer, Evaluator, Training, Combo)
SELECT
Tr.PersonName As Trainer,
Ev.PersonName As Evaluator,
Tn.TrainingID As Training,
Import.Column3 As Combo
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT Column3
FROM Import
) AS DistinctCombo
INNER JOIN Import On DistinctCombo.Column3 = Import.Column3
INNER JOIN People As Tr ON Import.Column1 = Tr.PersonName
INNER JOIN People AS Ev ON Import.Column2 = Ev.PersonName
INNER JOIN Trainings As Tn ON Import.[Item ID] = Tn.TrainingID;
```

Comment: [Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause for queries which include more than one join.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929533/77335)

Comment: Use Access query designer to get JOINs and parens correct then switch to SQL view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above on use of parentheses and having the query designer help a little, I was able to get it to work using the following:

```
INSERT INTO Surveys ( Trainer, Evaluator, Training, Combo )
SELECT DISTINCT p1.ID AS TrainerID, p2.ID AS TraineeID, t.ID AS TrainingD, 
s.Column3 AS Expr1
FROM ((Import AS s LEFT JOIN People AS p1 ON s.Column1 = p1.PersonName) 
LEFT JOIN 
People AS p2 ON s.Column2 = p2.PersonName) 
LEFT JOIN Trainings AS t ON s.[Item 
ID] = t.TrainingID;
```