# Access Error msg: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is the relevant SQL:

```
    strSQL_SRC = "SELECT tblGroupEmailType.GroupEmailTypeID, tblGroupEmailType.GroupID, " _
                    & "full_PGAL_Sth_Master.[Office-Email], " _
                    & "ztNumOfOfficeEmailAddrsForGroupID.[# of Office Email Addr] " _
                    & "FROM full_PGAL_Sth_Master " _
                            & "INNER JOIN tblGroupEmailType " _
                            & "ON full_PGAL_Sth_Master.GroupID = tblGroupEmailType.GroupID " _
                            & "INNER JOIN ztNumOfOfficeEmailAddrsForGroupID " _
                            & "ON tblGroupEmailType.GroupID = ztNumOfOfficeEmailAddrsForGroupID.GroupID " _
                    & "WHERE tblGroupEmailType.GroupID = " & lngGroupID
```

When I get to the line where the recordset is opened based upon the above SQL, I receive the following error message:

Err.Number: -2147217900
Err.Descr: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'full_PGAL_Sth_Master.GroupID = tblGroupEmailType.GroupID INNER JOIN ztNumOfOfficeEmailAddrsForGroupID ON tblGroupEmailType.GroupID = ztNumOfOfficeEmailAddrsForGroupID.GroupI'.

I looked very carefully at the code and I cannot spot anything.

I also created a query with the same tables, relationships and fields being returned. I supplied a specific number for the variable lngGroupID and that worked fine.

Maybe there is a missing space or something, but I can't see anything.

Comment: `lngGroupID` contains only digits?  If you Debug.Print `strSQL_SRC` can you run it in Access directly?

Comment: [Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause for queries which include more
than one join.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929533/77335)

Comment: Use Access query builder to get correct syntax.